# JOGL-3D, render dynamic string on surface of the objects

Tags: java, 3d, jogl

I am new to JOGL. I have requirement where I have to load thousands of elements (like cube) in the 3D world. This elements will have a unique label associated with each. Which should be shown on 1 of the face of the element (face depends on the camera view point).

I have successfully created the world & I am only loading the part which I am viewing. When there are only objects/elements loaded in the 2D. CPU usage is normal. But when I am introducing the Text (Using **TextRenderer**) the CPU usage goes very high (i.e. 30%+ from normal).

I want a efficient way in which I can render the text in the 3D world.
I am using below code for rendering the text.

```
textRenderer.begin3DRendering();
textRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
textRenderer.setSmoothing(true);
textRenderer.draw3D(name, x, y, object4D.vertex[0][2]+0f, 0.02f);
textRenderer.end3DRendering();
```

I have tried using **TextRegionUtil**.

```
try {
        font = FontFactory.get(FontFactory.JAVA).getDefault();
        renderState = RenderState.createRenderState(SVertex.factory());
        renderer = RegionRenderer.create(renderState, RegionRenderer.defaultBlendEnable, RegionRenderer.defaultBlendDisable);
        renderer.init(gl2, Region.DEFAULT_TWO_PASS_TEXTURE_UNIT);

        textUtil = new TextRegionUtil(Region.DEFAULT_TWO_PASS_TEXTURE_UNIT);

        pmv = renderer.getMatrix();
        pmv.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION);
        pmv.glScalef(0.1f, 0.1f, 01f);
        pmv.glLoadIdentity();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pmv.glPushMatrix();
    pmv.glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
    renderState.setColorStatic(1, 0, 0, 1);
    textUtil.drawString3D(gl2, renderer, font, fontSize, "Text", null, texSize);
    pmv.glPopMatrix();
```

But I am not able to get the view proper.
It shows view as below.

[image]

So please can any one help me out to solve this.

Comment: I advise you to ask your question on the official JogAmp forum as only a very few contributors come here. The legacy text renderer uses AWT under the hood, its high memory footprint isn't a surprise for me.

Comment: @gouessej; Thank you for your suggestion. I will surly ask this Q on official site. If you know than can you suggest some other API to render the text in 3D world using JOGL?

Comment: JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation, JMonkeyEngine, LibGDX, Unlicense-lib, Jzy3D, Xith3D, ... Most frameworks and engines with a JOGL backend have their own APIs to render text.